# dyld: Library not loaded (With Pyglet)

Tags: python, module, virtualenv

I'm a newbie with python, and I'm trying to run a small tuto with using OpenGL on OSX.

So my script is something like this:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

win = pyglet.window.Window()

@win.event
def on_draw():

    # Clear buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    # Draw some stuff
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glVertex2i(50, 50)
    glVertex2i(75, 100)
    glVertex2i(100, 150)
    glVertex2i(200, 200)
    glEnd()

pyglet.app.run()
```

I created a virtualenv like this in **myenv** directory:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages myenv
```

And I started my virtualenv like this:

```
source myenv/bin/activate
```

The problem is that when I run my script I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libclparser.dylib
    Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/import
    Reason: image not found
./helloWorld3D.py: line 2: 32482 Trace/BPT trap: 5       import pyglet
from: can't read /var/mail/pyglet.gl
./helloWorld3D.py: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./helloWorld3D.py: line 5: `win = pyglet.window.Window()'
```

But I previously installed 'pyglet' with 'pip' in my virtualenv like that:

```
sudo pip install pyglet
```

When I type 'pip list' in my virtualenv I get:

```
pip (1.5.6)
pyglet (1.1.4)
setuptools (3.6)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

And when I type 'yolk -l' in my virtualenv I get:

```
PyRSS2Gen       - 1.0.0        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
Python          - 2.7.5        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
Twisted         - 12.2.0       - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
altgraph        - 0.10.1       - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
bdist-mpkg      - 0.4.4        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
bonjour-py      - 0.3          - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
macholib        - 1.5          - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
matplotlib      - 1.1.1        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
modulegraph     - 0.10.1       - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
numpy           - 1.6.2        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
py2app          - 0.7.1        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
pyOpenSSL       - 0.13         - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)

pyobjc-core     - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-Automator - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-CoreData - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-CoreText - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-InterfaceBuilderKit - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-Message - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-PubSub - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-QTKit - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-Quartz - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-WebKit - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
pyobjc-framework-XgridFoundation - 2.3.2a0      - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC)
python-dateutil - 1.5          - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
pytz            - 2012d        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
scipy           - 0.11.0       - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
setuptools      - 0.6c12dev-r88846 - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
vboxapi         - 1.0          - active
virtualenv      - 1.11.6       - active
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7)
xattr           - 0.6.4        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
yolk            - 0.4.3        - active
zope.interface  - 3.8.0        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python)
```

So it seems that PyGlet is present with 'Pip' but not with 'yolk'....
Can somebody help me?